# Bayesian justification for AIC/BIC

Tags: bayesian, references, model-selection, aic, bic

Can someone point me to a straightforward and comprehensible Bayesian discussion justifying AIC and/or BIC? Or even better, can someone give a self-contained such discussion in this forum?

Comment: Burnham, Kenneth P., and David R. Anderson. "Multimodel inference understanding AIC and BIC in model selection." Sociological methods & research 33.2 (2004): 261-304.

Comment: In addition to Ben's comment, you can also look at [Kass/Raftery (1995): Bayes Factors](https://www.stat.washington.edu/~raftery/Research/PDF/kass1995.pdf), who discuss the BIC in detail. From their abstract: "The Schwarz criterion (or BIC) gives a rough approximation to the logarithm of the Bayes Factor, which is easy to use and does not require evaluation of prior distributions."